# Is there a topic in mathematics that study the combination of Real analysis and Number theory?.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, reference-request

i liked Real Analysis (although still not good) and i also liked number theory , especially modular arithmetic and diophantine equation;

and i was wondering, what if Real analysis and Number theory combined?
what is the result?, or what is the topic that combine real analysis and number theory?

Real analysis ∩ Number theory = ?

or maybe there is no combination of Real analysis and number theory.

Comment: It's called [analytic number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_number_theory).

Comment: Thanks, so that is the combination of real analysis and number theory.

Comment: The intersection of real analysis and numbers theory definitely is not analytic number theory. In fact, analytic number theory is much "larger" than this intersection.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a strange question, but [analytic number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_number_theory) maybe comes close to what you're looking for, although this is more about applying methods of complex (not real) analysis to solving number theoretic problems.

However, given the way that you've asked the question, I would encourage you to learn more about analysis and number theory respectively before looking at this again, because it seems like you might need a bit more experience in both topics to get a full appreciation of what it means to answer the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks, analytic number theory, that is the only answer i wanted.